# Pre-populating Cells with Multiple Values using Office JS

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

I am building an Excel Add In for Office 365 using Office JS. I am keen to provide some of the cells in the Excel Sheet to have pre-populated drop down of values for users to choose from while entering the data in the Excel Sheet. The template for the Excel sheet is generated the first time the user loads the Add In. Is there an Office -JS API which allows the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point in time we do not have an API to add Data Validation (which adds the drop-downs to Excel Cells).
Feel free to log a feature request at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/ and we will consider adding an API for this in the future.

-Philip, Software Developer on the Office Extensibility team

Answer (score 0):

Here I have added dropdown to the excel cell.

```
 Excel.run(function (context) {
    var currentWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var expensesTable = currentWorksheet.tables.add("A1:D1", true /*hasHeaders*/);
    expensesTable.name = "ExpensesTable";
    expensesTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [["Date", "Merchant", "Category", "Amount"]];
    expensesTable.rows.add(null /*add at the end*/, [
        ["1/1/2017", "The Phone Company", "Communications", "120"],
        ["1/2/2017", "Northwind Electric Cars", "Transportation", "142.33"],
        ["1/5/2017", "Best For You Organics Company", "Groceries", "27.9"],
        ["1/10/2017", "Coho Vineyard", "Restaurant", "33"],
        ["1/11/2017", "Bellows College", "Education", "350.1"],
        ["1/15/2017", "Trey Research", "Other", "135"],
        ["1/15/2017", "Best For You Organics Company", "Groceries", "97.88"]
    ]);
    var range = currentWorksheet.getRange("C2:C200");
    range.dataValidation.clear();
    range.dataValidation.rule = {
        list: {
            inCellDropDown: true,
            source: "Groceries, Education, Other,Transportation",
            autofitColumns: true
        }
    };
    //range.dataValidation.errorAlert = {
    //    message: "Sorry, only Selected value are allowed",
    //    showAlert: true,
    //    style: "Stop",
    //    title: "Other value Entered"
    //};
    list.find();

    return context.sync();
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```